# Apache Tomcat 7 on windows 2008: how to make two hosts point to same website

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat, java, tomcat7

I’m new to Apache Tomcat.  I have been asked to point new domain name to the existing domain name.  E.g. We have https://xyz.abc.com, we want new domain name http://123.abc.com to point to xyz.abc.com.  The Apache Tomcat 7 server is installed Windows 2008 R2 server.  We have created the DNS entry for 123.abc.com Can someone tell me how to do this? Do I need to create a virtual host and if so how. How do I restart tomcat server on windows 2008 R2?

I read that if I modify server.xml then I need to restart Tomcat. How do I restart Tomcat?

I have a following entry in config/server.xml file:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

---

Will this work. I want 123.abc.com to go to xyz.abc.com. So 123.abc.com is an alias for xyz.abc.com. Both the sites are pointing to the same appbase.

```
<Host name="www.knowledgefolders.com" 
  appBase="D:/webpage_demos/akc"
  unpackWARs="true" 
  autoDeploy="true" 
  xmlValidation="false" 
  xmlNamespaceAware="false">

   <Alias>knowledgefolders.com</Alias>

   <Alias>www.knowledgefolders.net</Alias>
   <Alias>knowledgefolders.net</Alias>

   <Alias>www.knowledgefolders.org</Alias>
   <Alias>knowledgefolders.org</Alias>

   <Alias>www.satyakomatineni.com</Alias>
   <Alias>www.kavithakomatineni.com</Alias>

   <Context path="" docBase="D:/webpage_demos/akc" 
       debug="0" reloadable="false"/>
   <Context path="/akc" docBase="D:/webpage_demos/akc" 
      debug="0" reloadable="false"/>
</Host>
```

Notice how all of the following host names point to the same web app, akc (which was the previous name for Knowledge Folders).

```
knowledgefolders.com
www.knowledgefolders.com
knowledgefolders.net
www.knowledgefolders.net
knowledgefolders.org
www.knowledgefolders.org
www.satyakomatineni.com
www.kavithakomatineni.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a new valve for [the rewrite engine](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html). It's almost the same as for Apache's httpd server's mod_rewrite. Alternatively you could install Apache/Nginx HTTP and redirect on it.

Comment: I'm very new with no experience with Tomcat. Can you explain. It's a production server so I do not wish the install another web server. I don't understand what the valve is.

Comment: You should create a test box to practice/test then, not make untested changes on a production box Running tomcat behind httpd/nginx is quite common. What are you familiar with?

Comment: I know IIS.  So you are saying creating alias like above won't work? I thought if I add line similiar to this  <Alias>www.knowledgefolders.net</Alias> inside my host tag it should work.